# I cant generate pop up box with more then one generate link in a page using jquery

Tags: jquery

i am doing  stuff with generate popup in more then one   link using jquery.I can generate pop up box when click on first link,but cant generate in the case case of other links.In the case of 'Click here1' ,get popup box ,but in the case of 'Click here2' and 'Click here3' ,dont get popup box.How i solve these issue?Anybody help me?

My html code is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.leanModal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-   awesome.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<div class="container">
    <a id="modal_trigger" href="#modal" class="btn">Click here to Login or register</a> 
</div>
<div class="container">
    <a id="modal_trigger" href="#modal" class="btn">Click here1 </a>    
</div>

<div class="container">
    <a id="modal_trigger" href="#modal" class="btn">Click here2</a> 
</div>

<div class="container">
    <a id="modal_trigger" href="#modal" class="btn">Click here3</a> 
</div>

<div id="modal" class="popupContainer" style="display:none;width:700px;height:500px;margin-top:-105px;">
    <header class="popupHeader">
        <span class="header_title">Sales Details</span>
        <span class="modal_close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
    </header>

    <section class="popupBody">
        iui
    </section>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#modal_trigger").leanModal({top : 200, overlay : 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close" });
</script>
```

My jquery code in jquery.leanModal.min.js is

```
   <script>
 (function($)
   {
     $.fn.extend(
     {
         leanModal:function(options)
      {
      var defaults=   {top:100,overlay:0.5,closeButton:null};
      var overlay=$("<div id='lean_overlay'>       </div>");
      $("body").append(overlay);
      options=$.extend(defaults,options);
      return this.each(function()
      {
         var o=options;$(this).click(function(e)
         {
           var   modal_id=$(this).attr("href");
           $("#lean_overlay").click(function()
           {
            close_modal(modal_id)
            });
            $(o.closeButton).click(function() 
               {
                 close_modal(modal_id)
               });
                 var modal_height=$(modal_id).outerHeight();
                 var modal_width=$(modal_id).outerWidth();
                 $("#lean_overlay").css({"display":"block",opacity:0});
                 $("#lean_overlay").fadeTo(200,o.overlay);
                 $(modal_id).css({"display":"block","position":"fixed",
                                  "opacity":0,"z-      index":11000,"left":50+"%",
                                 "margin-left":-     (modal_width/2)+"px","top":o.top+"px"
                                 });
                 $(modal_id).fadeTo(200,1);
                 e.preventDefault()
         })
      });
                 function close_modal(modal_id)  
                    {
                       $("#lean_overlay").fadeOut(200);
                       $(modal_id).css({"display":"none"})
                     }
   }
  })
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Please format your code so it's human-readable, I left my R2 unit at home.

Comment: hello, you want to show div tag when user click on click in link right ?

Comment: you wan to div tag popup right

Comment: yes,i i want to show the the div id model as popup box when click on 'Click here1','Click here2','Click here3'

Comment: Formatted your code, what is with the extraneous close tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using "class" instead of "id" for modal_trigger.

Answer (score 0):

this is only example, to you know how you can work so try this and replace your style and content

try this..

```
 <div class="container">
 <a id="modal_trigger" href="#modal" class="btn">Click here to Login or register</a>    
</div>
<div class="container">
<a id="modal_trigger" href="#modal" class="btn">Click here1 </a>    
</div>

<div class="container">
<a id="modal_trigger" href="#modal" class="btn">Click here2</a> 
</div>

<div class="container">
<a id="modal_trigger" href="#modal" class="btn">Click here3</a> 
</div>

<div id="modal" class="popupContainer" 
style="display:none;width:700px;height:500px;margin-  t op:-105px;">
    <header class="popupHeader">
        <span class="header_title">Sales Details</span>
        <span class="modal_close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
    </header>

    <section class="popupBody">
        iui
    </section>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".container a").click(function(){
        $plus=$(this).text();
        $("#modal").hide(500);
        $("#modal").show(500);
        $(".popupBody").text($plus);
    });
});
```

live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Be6dq/

thank you...